# Block MSTP on port Dell N series networking

Tags: spanning-tree, dell

I am noticing that our Dell N4000 series switch connected to a stack of Cisco devices is constantly attempting to change spanning tree topology. The Cisco switch is our Internet connection and a fiber loop that connects to our other offices.

My logs are:
`<189> Nov  6 09:34:36 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7355 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1
<189> Nov  6 09:34:35 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7354 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change: 0, Unit: 1
<189> Nov  6 09:34:35 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7353 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1
<189> Nov  6 09:28:26 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7352 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1
<189> Nov  6 09:28:25 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7351 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change: 0, Unit: 1
<189> Nov  6 09:28:25 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7350 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1
<189> Nov  6 08:38:20 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7347 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1
<189> Nov  6 08:38:19 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7346 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change: 0, Unit: 1
<189> Nov  6 08:38:19 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7345 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1
<189> Nov  6 08:29:16 SW105-1 TRAPMGR[dot1s_task]: traputil.c(777) 7344 %% Spanning Tree Topology Change Received: MSTID: 0 Te1/0/1`

The only config on the port is:
`switchport mode general
switchport general pvid 10
switchport general allowed vlan add 10`

Would it be best to enable tcn guard and bpdu filter on this port?

Comment: Do you want to disable STP on this ports or do you want to make STP work properly? In my experience, I never implement STP between core switches and ISP routers.

Comment: You may want to look at this question: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23679/native-vlan-cisco-catalyst-and-layer-3-switch/23680#23680

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like my best option is to turn off STP for this port.